# Didn't Down Vote, but showing I did and wont let me undo!

Tags: bug, voting

I looked at a question, added a comment, then went back to my main page. About 2 minutes later I see I have a -1 reputation so I go to check it out and it says I downvoted something..

I don't down vote ANYTHING, and wanted to immediately rectify this issue, but going to the page wont allow me to remove my down vote claiming it's Locked unless the question is edited..

THIS MAKES NO SENSE!

Allow people to up vote or down vote at their will without it locking you into place. What if someone accidently clicks (which I vehemently deny doing) or some other glitch occurs (such as this instance)?

Answer (score 2):

There is a grace period of about 5 minutes where you can change your vote.  After that, your vote is locked in.

More information is here: [Why do votes get locked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80762/why-do-votes-get-locked)

It's a matter of one reputation point, so I wouldn't sweat it too much.  If you're really concerned about it, you can always edit the question (most questions have *something* that can be improved -- spelling, grammar, formatting, clarity, etc.), then change your vote after the edit.

Comment: I don't care about the -1 to me, but giving a downvote gives - to the person who wrote the response, and they didn't deserve it. And beyond that, I had scrolled on the screen but clicked nothing until the comment, then submitted the comment and left the page. At no point did I click the downvote, nor approach it. My only idea is that perhaps the spacebar or some other keystroke affected it.